# Invalid expression term ':' in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Just got started with asp.net MVC. Created my first controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

And tried to set show the `CurrentTime` in the view like

```
<%: ViewData["CurrentTime"] %>
```

But its giving the below error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'
```

**Update**: i'm using framework 3.5

Comment: <%: %> is an ASP.NET 4.x-specific syntax.  Can you confirm that you're running on ASP.NET 4.0 / 4.5 instead of ASP.NET 3.5?

Comment: @Levi you were right, i was running on 3.5 and the moment i moved to 4.0/4.5 it works fine now..thnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. Try

```
<%= ViewData["CurrentTime"] %>
```

Instead of

```
<%: ViewData["CurrentTime"] %>
```

Comment: dat worked ....strange i was following the [codeproject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in-7) and dey have it wrong dere...

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
    <%: (string)ViewData["CurrentTime"] %>
```

Stil, i think that you should try to use Razor. Its much frindly and it has a lot more features than aspx.